# Confusion with the styles in Ionic app + Bootstrap

Tags: css, ionic-framework, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have Ionic app in which I use angular-ui-bootstrap Datepicker. To apply bootstrap style only on this datepicker I apply `class="bootstrap"` on `div` element (I import bootstrap using Sass and wrap it with `.bootstrap`):

```
<div class="bootstrap">
    <uib-datepicker ng-model="dt" class="well well-sm"></uib-datepicker>
</div>
```

It works fine. But Ionic styles does apply on elements inside this div, I mean month name and arrows are shown incorrectly.  I try redefine styles but without any success. This style don't works

```
.tr {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xwmxQL

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find my mistake. Instead of `tr` I must use `th`:

```
.th {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Probably there are some name collisions between the Ionic CSS and the Bootstrap CSS. I would suggest coping the CSS that is related to that classes from Bootstrap you are using and paste it into the CSS file of the project.

Hope it helps.

Comment: The problem is that I can't find classes in Bootstrap related with this elements.